# Python: writing to csv

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I'm attempting to write a script that will read documents, and write into a csv the total number of each unique word for each document.  I am able to open and read each document (from "doc_list"), as well as generate the frequencies of each word (stored in "word_frequencies").  The issue I am having is writing it out to a csv.
I need the top column to be the unique words (I have generated "corpus_tokens" which contains all words in any of the documents) and the first row to be the name of each of the documents ("doc_list"). Then I need to fill in the frequencies ("word_frequencies").

Does anybody know how to do this?
Thank you.

**EDIT**

Current (extremely faulty) code:

```
import csv

def unigramgen(self, name):
    '''
    test function to generate unigram tables
    ::
    '''
    print ("check 1")
    docstats = MACdoc()
    prints('Opening', name + '.csv')
    write_csv = csv.writer(open(name + ".csv", "w"), lineterminator='\n')
    doc_name = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    col_names = ['Doc Name']
    for i in docstats.corpus_types():
        col_names.append(i)
    print ("check 2")
    write_csv.writerow(col_names + '\n')

    i = 0

    prints('Writing data to table...')
    print ("check 3")
    for document in self.document_list:
        prints('Writing data for', document, '...')
        name = doc_name

        freqs = docstats.wordfreq[i, :]
        freqs = [str(freq) for freq in freqs]

        row = name + freqs

        write_csv.writerow(row + '\n')

        i += 1
    print ("check 4")
    return True
```

*note: MACdoc is a class that created the frequencies of words (among many other things).  It was created by someone else for a different project but appears to work pretty well.

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain your code. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at and help you improve it. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use the "edit" button to update your question. Good luck!

Comment: Instead of talking abstract, provide a [mcve]. Also take a loot at this article: [how to ask the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)

Comment: `Does anybody know how to do this?` Yes, I know how to do this. Now, if you were to show my the structure of your variables, and the code that you've attempted, and how it's failed, I might even be able to show you how to fix it

Comment: So, what is the problem with your current code? We can't run it, since it uses a class we don't have access too, so we can't find out for ourselves. Are you getting the wrong output? No output? An exception? If an exception, please provide the traceback. If you're getting wrong output, give us a (short) example of the desired output and the actual output you're getting instead.